# Can't assign new value to property

Tags: c#, properties

I am talking about the property `PageSettings.PrinterResolution`. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.printerresolution(v=vs.110).aspx) this property has a `setter`, same as the property `PrinterResolution.X`, even though I can't set a new value to it. The property still contains it's earlier value and not the new assigned one.

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();    
//assigning a printer to `pd`, etc...

//premise: pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X has currently the value 200
```

Now I try to assign a new `int` value to `X`:

```
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X = 300;
```

But after checking it's value `pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X` still contains `200`. I just figured out to assign a new `PrinterResolution` object with set values for `X` and `Y` to `pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution` to change the values to my needs.

```
PrinterResolution changedRes = new PrinterResolution();
changedRes.X = 200;
changedRes.Y = 200;

pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution = changedRes;
```

So why can't I set the values of the property? And especially why is there a documented `setter` even though it's not *"usable"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Printing/PageSettings.cs,1bafb486392529af) of `PageSettings` you see that the `PrinterResolution` is always re-requested from the API (as long as you don't set the `PrinterResolution` property manually):

```
public PrinterResolution PrinterResolution {
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Process, ResourceScope.Process)]
    get {
        if (printerResolution == null) {
            IntSecurity.AllPrintingAndUnmanagedCode.Assert();

            IntPtr modeHandle = printerSettings.GetHdevmode();
            IntPtr modePointer = SafeNativeMethods.GlobalLock(new HandleRef(this, modeHandle));
            SafeNativeMethods.DEVMODE mode = (SafeNativeMethods.DEVMODE) UnsafeNativeMethods.PtrToStructure(modePointer, typeof(SafeNativeMethods.DEVMODE));

            PrinterResolution result = PrinterResolutionFromMode(mode);

            SafeNativeMethods.GlobalUnlock(new HandleRef(this, modeHandle));
            SafeNativeMethods.GlobalFree(new HandleRef(this, modeHandle));

            return result;
        }
        else
            return printerResolution;
    }
    set {
        printerResolution = value;
    }
}
```

So as long as you don't set `PageSettings.PrinterResolution` manually, a new `PrinterResolution` instance is loaded from the API everytime you access the `PageSettings.PrinterResolution` getter. And this new instance contains the original `X` value again. The instance for which you set `X` before is discarded.

As to the *why* it is like that I don't know enough about.